# Combining multiple audio files in ruby

Tags: ruby, audio

I'm trying to combine two or more audio files in ruby. I don't need to concatenate the files, but rather combine or merge them. For example, if I have one audio file that is the guitar part to a song, and one audio file that is the bass part, I want to combine the two files and have one file with both the guitar and bass parts.

Is this possible, and if so could somebody point me in the right direction? Googling didn't help much.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: you can use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to mix the audio.

Comment: Thanks yeah I found that. It's not a good fit for this project because I need to mix the audio programmatically and on demand as people use a website.

Answer (score 1):

Exists `sox` Unix tool which could help you. Unfortunately there is no good ruby wrapper.
Two I found are out of date:

- https://github.com/afhbl/rsox
- https://github.com/Beirdo/sox-ruby

In shell you can easy merge those file with sox command like this:

> sox -m  ./bass.mp3  ./guitar.mp3  ./rock-n-roll.mp3

So you can do it in Ruby by wrapping shell command, e.g.:

```
def merge_sounds(file1, file2, output_file)
  system "sox -m #{file1} #{file} #{output_file}"
end
```